# select one value change another select box value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select box. 2nd box change value according to first select box.

like if user select "single" in option on first select 2nd box value change and show that value
1. (Single) 3ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)
2. (Single) 3ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)
3. (Single) 3ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)
4. (Single) 3ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.product-addon-add-mattress option').hide();
$('#pa_bed-size').change(function(){

var bedSize = $(this).val();

$('.product-addon-add-mattress option').hide();
    var single = "single",
    SmallDouble ="small-double",
    Double ="double";

    if(bedSize.indexOf(single) != -1){
       var name = $('#pa_bed-size').val().split(' ')[ 0 ];  
    $('.product-addon-add-mattress select option').each().val(single);
 
     }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="pa_bed-size" class="" name="attribute_pa_bed-size" >
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="single" class="attached enabled">Single</option>
    <option value="small-double" class="attached enabled">Small Double</option>
    <option value="double" class="attached enabled">Double</option>
    <option value="king" class="attached enabled">King</option>
    <option value="super-king" class="attached enabled">Super King</option>
</select>



<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-2696-add-mattress-0">
    <option value="">Select an option...</option>
    <option data-raw-price="0" data-price="" value="not-required-1">Not Required</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="single-3ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-2">(Single) 3ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="single-3ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-3">(Single) 3ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="single-3ft-pocket-1000-mattress-4">(Single) 3ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="single-3ft-pocket-2000-mattress-5">(Single) 3ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="small-double-4ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-6">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="small-double-4ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-7">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="small-double-4ft-pocket-1000-mattress-8">(Small Double) 4ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="small-double-4ft-pocket-2000-mattress-9">(Small Double) 4ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="double-4ft6-spring-memory-foam-mattress-10">(Double) 4ft6 Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="double-4ft6-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-11">(Double) 4ft6 Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="double-4ft6-pocket-1000-mattress-12">(Double) 4ft6 Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="double-4ft6-pocket-2000-mattress-13">(Double) 4ft6 Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="king-6ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-14">(King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="king-6ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-15">(King) 6ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="king-6ft-pocket-1000-mattress-16">(King) 6ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="king-6ft-pocket-2000-mattress-17">(King) 6ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="super-king-6ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-18">(Super King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="super-king-6ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-19">(Super King) 6ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="super-king-6ft-pocket-1000-mattress-20">(Super King) 6ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="super-king-6ft-pocket-2000-mattress-21">(Super King) 6ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d3h71apw/3/

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you fully functional implementation and I don't say it's the best way, however I am going to give you a guideline.

**Please check the below way:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.product-addon-add-mattress option').hide();
  $('#pa_bed-size').change(function(){

  var bedSize = $(this).val();
  
  $('.addon option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().indexOf(bedSize) == 0) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
  })
  
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_bed-size" class="" name="attribute_pa_bed-size" >
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="single" class="attached enabled">Single</option>
    <option value="small-double" class="attached enabled">Small Double</option>
    <option value="double" class="attached enabled">Double</option>
    <option value="king" class="attached enabled">King</option>
    <option value="super-king" class="attached enabled">Super King</option>
</select>



<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-2696-add-mattress-0">
    <option value="">Select an option...</option>
    <option data-raw-price="0" data-price="" value="not-required-1">Not Required</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="single-3ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-2">(Single) 3ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="single-3ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-3">(Single) 3ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="single-3ft-pocket-1000-mattress-4">(Single) 3ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="single-3ft-pocket-2000-mattress-5">(Single) 3ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="small-double-4ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-6">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="small-double-4ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-7">(Small Double) 4ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="small-double-4ft-pocket-1000-mattress-8">(Small Double) 4ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="small-double-4ft-pocket-2000-mattress-9">(Small Double) 4ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="double-4ft6-spring-memory-foam-mattress-10">(Double) 4ft6 Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="double-4ft6-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-11">(Double) 4ft6 Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="double-4ft6-pocket-1000-mattress-12">(Double) 4ft6 Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="double-4ft6-pocket-2000-mattress-13">(Double) 4ft6 Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="king-6ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-14">(King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="king-6ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-15">(King) 6ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="king-6ft-pocket-1000-mattress-16">(King) 6ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="king-6ft-pocket-2000-mattress-17">(King) 6ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="145" data-price="145" value="super-king-6ft-spring-memory-foam-mattress-18">(Super King) 6ft Spring Memory Foam Mattress (£145.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="super-king-6ft-spring-orthopedic-foam-mattress-19">(Super King) 6ft Spring Orthopedic Foam Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="185" data-price="185" value="super-king-6ft-pocket-1000-mattress-20">(Super King) 6ft Pocket 1000 Mattress (£185.00)</option>
    <option data-raw-price="225" data-price="225" value="super-king-6ft-pocket-2000-mattress-21">(Super King) 6ft Pocket 2000 Mattress (£225.00)</option>
</select>
```

Please don't hesitate to let me know if you have any query.

Comment: thanks for replay.
I also wrote the code for temporary

Comment: You are most welcome, if it's helpful please accept the answer.

Comment: Did you get this solution helpful?

Comment: No Bro. this is temporary solution not proper solution.

Comment: open that link [link](https://jsfiddle.net/d3h71apw/3/)
i do not want hide show in jquery. I want to match value in (if condition) or Otherwise there is another solution.